# Highcharts: chart with strange characters

Tags: utf-8, highcharts, diacritics

Highcharts: chart with strange characters when I use characters with diacritic accents like "à" or "í".
The charts looks well but when I export it in .png or .jpg the letters are wrong.

This only occurs with IE8.

Any idea?

http://jsfiddle.net/L8n16zkx/1/

```
$(function () {

$('#container').highcharts({

    title: {
        text: 'prova accents à é'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click the button to download as PNG/JPEG/SVG'
    },

    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 126.0, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

});
});
```

problem: jsfiddle don't work on IE8

offline-export don't work on IE8 because use canvas.

The project use:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-15">
```

and I can't change it.

Comment: Do you have live example of your issue?

Comment: hi,

http://jsfiddle.net/L8n16zkx/1/
problem: jsfiddle don't work on IE8

offline-export don't work on IE8 because use canvas.

The project use:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-15">

and I can't change it.

Comment: Could you provide a code for a .html file that is working in, for example, Chrome? You mentioned that this is an issue only for IE8, but I am unable to make this work in Chrome. This problem looks like an encoding problem - UTF-8 encoding is required. More info: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#non-ascii

Comment: That woks for chrome. The charts looks bad only in exported pics, not in the page.

Comment: If the problem is only in exporting then it's an encoding conflict explained in the link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the function **utf8_encode()**